# mfc - float to string, storing it in file and read it from file

Tags: string, file, mfc, output

I am using visual studio 2010 to create MFC application. 
I have to use a dialog with 2 edit controls, values typed into edit controls i have to add and print on screen like: "Addend1 + Addend2 = Result".
Now, i used _ttof() function to get float from string, which function do i use to get string from float after i add two values?
And, after do that, i will have to store it in file and read it. I did it like this:

```
void CseminarskiDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
```

{

```
if (ar.IsStoring())
{
    // TODO: add storing code here
    ar << m_text;
}
else
{

    // TODO: add loading code here

    ar >> m_text;

}
```

}

Does this line "ar>> m_text" mean that value stored into file will be read into m_text and shown on screen? Can i do this

```
ar>>m_text1>> "+" >>m_text2>> "=" >>m_text;
```

to have output like "Addend1 + Addend2 = Result"?

In ExView.cpp file, do i have to add some lines to do the ouput, or the last command can be function to do float-> string?

Sorry on my bad English :D

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way!

Do not use text or CString variables in your dialog box.  Instead define variables that are either float or double.  I guess you're using float...

```
// members of class CZBroj in your ZBroj.h

float m_fVar1;
float m_fVar2;

void CZBroj::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
   DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_fVar1); // if not IDC_EDIT1, change to correct ID
   DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT2, m_fVar2);
}

 void CseminarskiView::OnEditZbroj()
{
   CseminarskiDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
   CZbroj dlg; // deklariranje dijaloga
   dlg.m_fVar1 = 3.4; //use whatever value you want to initialize with
   dlg.m_fVar2 = 1.414; // again, init with whatever you want, or be sure to init in constructor
   if (IDOK == dlg.DoModal())
   {
       // respond appropriately
       // dlg.m_fVar1,dlg.m_fVar2 will contain the edited values...magic of DDX_Text
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this to convert a float to string:

```
CString s;
s.Format(_T("%f"), floatvariable);
```

It can also be used to build your desired output string:

```
s.Format(_T("%f + %f = %f"), Addend1, Addend2, Result);
```

The CArchive stuff does not display anything to screen and does not concatenate strings. In fact the CArchive does not create an ordinary text file so it may not be appropriate at all for what you want in your file.